# xpath query not considering the decimal

Tags: xpath

I'm using the following xpath query

```
//div/span[@class='you-pay-price  ' and 1]
```

but I'm getting the result is in thousands. that is if the price is 250.9 the result would 250,900

how can I fix this issue. [Link to the source](https://www.xcite.com/huawei-p30-pro-512gb-phone-amber-sunrise.html)

regards,

Comment: XPath isn't in the business of converting or formatting data. Something else in your environment is doing that. Add some more tags so we know what you're working with.

Comment: Try to give a minimal reproducible example with your code, a sample of input, of the output that you want and of the output that you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to keep only one decimal :

```
(substring-before(//div/span[@class='you-pay-price'],' KD')*100)div 100
```

Output : `259.9`

Comment: Thank you, the following code worked find for me

```
.//*[@itemprop='price']/@content
```

Comment: Nice. Use my XPath expression as an alternative.